# Hecke $L$-series exercise in Silverman's Advanced Topics in Arithmetic of EC

Tags: elliptic-curves, dirichlet-series

I would like to refer you to 2.30 & 2.32 in Silverman's book Advanced Topics in the Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves.

2.30(b)[(c) in errata]: Suppose $\mathfrak{P}$ remains inert in $L'$, say $\mathfrak{P}R_{L'}=\mathfrak{P}'$. Prove that 
$$q_{\mathfrak{P}}^2=q_{\mathfrak{P}'},\quad a_{\mathfrak{P}}=0,\quad\psi_{E/L'}(\mathfrak{P}')=-q_{\mathfrak{P}}.$$
2.32(a) Prove that the local $L$-series of $E$ at $\mathfrak{P}$ is given by
$$ L_{\mathfrak{P}}(T,E/L) = \left\{ 
  \begin{array}{l l}
    \cdots & \quad \mathfrak{P}\text{ splits}\\
    1-\psi_{E/L'}(\mathfrak{P}')T & \quad \text{$\mathfrak{P}$ inert}\\
    \cdots & \quad \mathfrak{P}\text{ ramifies}\\
  \end{array} \right.$$

In the beginning of the chapter, we have that if $E$ has good reduction (in this case, we have good reduction because of 2.30(c))$$L_{\mathfrak{P}}(T,E/L) = 1-a_{\mathfrak{P}}T+q_{\mathfrak{P}}T^2$$
So is the question missing a power of 2 in $T$? Should it be $1-\psi_{E/L'}(\mathfrak{P}')T^2\text{when is $\mathfrak{P}$ inert}$? I'm quite sure I've made a mistake somewhere, because of 2.32(b). Thanks for the help! (If it helps, I can print the question; say so in the comments and I'll do it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the question. The subtlety is that $T$ is not constant with respect to the fields $L'$ and $L$. My mistake was that I took $T$ to be the same in both fields when in reality it is not.

\begin{align*}
L(s,E/L)&=\prod_{\text{$\mathfrak{P}$ in $L$}}\left(1-a_{\mathfrak{P}}q_{\mathfrak{P}}^{-2}+q_{\mathfrak{P}}^{1-2s}\right)^{-1}\\
&=\prod_{\text{$\mathfrak{P}$ in $L$}}\left(1+q_{\mathfrak{P}}^{1-2s}\right)^{-1}\\
&=\prod_{\text{$\mathfrak{P}$ in $L$}}\left(1+q_{\mathfrak{P}}q_{\mathfrak{P}}^{-2s}\right)^{-1}\\
&=\prod_{\text{$\mathfrak{P}$ in $L$}}\left(1+q_{\mathfrak{P}}q_{\mathfrak{P}'}^{-s}\right)^{-1}\\
&=\prod_{\text{$\mathfrak{P}'$ in $L'$}}\left(1-\psi_{E/L'}(\mathfrak{P}')q_{\mathfrak{P}'}^{-s}\right)^{-1}\\
&=L(s,\psi_{E/L'})
\end{align*}